JSSDK Unknown Host domain error even after adding Allowed Domains for the JavaScript SDK
I'm getting this error after adding the correct domain to the Allowed Domains for the JavaScript SDK field in the App Dashboard.
JSSDK Unknown Host domain
The Domain you are hosting the Facebook Javascript SDK is not in your app's Javascript SDK host domain list. Please specify your host domain in App dashboard login settings.
Is it because my domain runs in a google site? When I open it as my domain then it doesn't change to sites.google... just my domain remains in the address bar. But when I open the site by clicking on view published site then it opens the sites.google... address. I also tried to add https://sites.google.com/ to the Allowed Domains for the JavaScript SDK field but it doesn't work. Is there anything else that I can try?

Do I need to share my domain address? Here it is if that helps: https://www.redrok.online/sign-up

So when you are accessing the site via your redrok.online domain, it works? And only accessing it via sites.google.com is the problem? Is the latter really a case you need to pay much attention to? Regular users aren't supposed to access your site via the Google URL to begin with, are they?
